# rpart warning message and then no proper rpart plot formed

Tags: r, rpart

I tried `rpart` and I got the following error and rpart plot only showed 0

> Warning messages: error was: Setting row names on a tibble is
>   deprecated.

No proper rpart plot was formed. The below is the plot that was generated:

[image]

```
rpart.oc<-function(seed,training,labels,otrl){
  ol<-makeSOCKcluster(6,type="SOCK")
  registerDoSNOW(ol)
  set.seed(seed)
  rpart.oc<-train(x=training,y=labels,method="rpart",tuneLength=30,trControl=otrl)
  stopCluster(ol)
  return(rpart.oc)
}
rpart.1.cv.1o<-rpart.oc(94622,rpart.train.1o,of.label,otrl.3))


Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1898 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ so : Factor w/ 10 levels "",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ a    : num  63 7 3 45 2 4 69 0 7 0 ...
 $ n   : Factor w/ 5 levels "","",..: 3 2 2 1 2 3 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ s: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ d   : Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 6 6 7 7 5 5 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ c: Factor w/ 7 levels "A","C",..: 6 2 4 2 2 4 1 2 7 2
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: @bob dalgleish added should i clarify some more ?

Comment: actually i ran random forest then cross validation from  that i got otrl.3 and then rpart and rpart plot.